# Android content uri id as string

Tags: android, mongodb, sqlite, uri, android-contentprovider

In my Android app i use SQLite with content provider. For some (backend) reasons, my tables have _id primary key as VARCHAR.

The problem is:

I need to use content uri with appended id. In all examples what i saw content uri with id looks as

```
content://<autority>/<model_or_table>/<long_id>
```

and adds to UriMatcher as

```
UriMatcher.add(autority, model_or_id + "/#", uri_id)
```

and of course thats "/#" matching id works only with digits.

My question is:

There is any way to use content uri with appended String id? Typical id is something like

```
50c11d774e5e1b99698b6879
```

and typical content uri must be as

```
content://com.my.app.autority/Users/50c11d774e5e1b99698b6879
```

and how to work with uri like this and UriMatcher?

I know that i can write selection directive (WHERE _id = "50c11d774e5e1b99698b6879") to query method, but i need exactly URI or way to project unique string ids to the unique long values in SQLiteDB.

There is any way? Thanks in adwance) Sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to documentation about creating a Content Provider found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html). Specifically, refer to heading `Content URI patterns`. As you correctly pointed out the `#` is a wildcard which will match single rows with an integer ID. The `*` wildcard will not match single rows with non-numeric IDs.

As far as I can tell, the `UriMatcher` class cannot help you in this case.

Please also refer to the `UriMatcher` Reference page [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html).